# How to create a list of untranslated content in views?

Tags: views, 8, i18n-l10n

I want to create a list of all nodes that has not been translated into a specific language - how do I do that?

I'm using Drupal 8.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the [Translation Views](https://www.drupal.org/project/translation_views) module.

Answer (score -2):

I assume you have 
enabled core module `language` and `content translation`
and added a 2nd language in `admin/config/regional/language`
and you should also have `enable translation` and probably `language selection` for a specific content type lets say `basic page`

[image]

content translation core has a views filter for the purpose of finding the nodes that need translation or ones that need to REVISE their translation (that are outdated)

create a view `untranslated` and add 2 filters 
`Content: Default translation (= True)` 
`Content: Revision translation affected (!= False)`

[image: untranslated view]

NOTE: this will originally show you all untranslated but if a translation flags other translations as `flag other translations as outdated` then those SOURCE nodes will also be included in the list

[image: outdate other translations]

Comment: Hi, thanks for tips! I tried follow this step-by-step, I have installed translation modules, set the content type to translatable, and created the 2 filters as you explain, however what I see is that I get the source translation of the node, no matter what language I check. There is no list of untranslated nodes, and the list always output "yes" no matter if the node is translated or not. Any tips for what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: yes you do get the SOURCE nodes that are untranslated ... 
"no matter what language I check" what does this mean ? 
I would suggest you start from a clean install drupal 8 and rebuild it as there might be a conflict with a module that you are using

Comment: Same issue here as @user11448, the view displays all source nodes (regardless of whether they have translations or not).  It does not filter out content that does not have any translations.

Comment: Does not work, same issue as user11448 and leon.fk, using Drupal v8.5.6